# Run Java with multiple classes on Netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans, package

is there any good tutorial where I can learn how to run a Java Application with multiple classes (one class after the other, in a package) on Netbeans IDE 7.4?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "one class after the other"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible, and I don't even know why you'd have multiple mains, but one way to do this *manually* is simply to write another `main` instead and call all the classes you want to run.

```
public class MultiMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(InsertionSort.class);
        InsertionSort.main(args);
        System.out.println(ConsoleTest.class);
        ConsoleTest.main(args);
        System.out.println(Main.class);
        Main.main(args);
    }

}
```

Also, maybe something like unit tests are what you are looking for ...?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Every class will have multiple objects in it. There will be one main-public class and then there will be other private classes which will run in the main class' package.

Comment: ariti, that sounds like it should just work, without your doing anything fancy at all.  What problems are you encountering?

Comment: It works just fine like a script, but when it comes to OOP, I need multiple classes (and objects) and I can't figure out how can I call a class into an other class. So as the program runs, it will uses more than one file from a directory.